# Visual Studio webtest cannot find its own assembly

Tags: visual-studio-2017, load-testing, web-testing

I have a Visual Studio web test that is using a custom JSON Extraction Rule. Initially the rule was in the web test's project/assembly. When running the test, it fails during the extraction, saying

```
Could not load file or assembly `ProjectName, Version=1.0.0.0` or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

In the same test I'm using a custom validation rule defined in a different project and this is working, so I copied the Extraction Rule to the other project. I manually edited the webtest XML to use the other project's namespace and assembly name. I re-run the web test after saving/cleaning/building.

I get the same error.

I confirm in my testsettings file that I've said to deploy the bin folder of the project. And the other project. And some other random stuff just out of desperation, it seems.

Same error.

If I take the non-working web test and click Generate Code it produces a TestNameCoded.cs file in the root of the test project which does exactly what the webtest does. **If I run that, it works fine.**

Why do Visual Studio Web Tests ever have problems loading **their own assembly**? How can I get this web test to work without having to generate (and maintain) a coded test?

Comment: Please describe the custom rule in more detail. Is it self contained or does it call code in other DLLs? If it uses other DLLs are they available? The error message includes *"or one of its dependencies"*. Have you checked the `Testresults\...\` directory to ensure all the files have been deployed?

Comment: It uses Newtonsoft.Json, but nothing else. A validation rule from the same assembly also uses Json and is working in this same test. I’ll check the output folder more thoroughly, thanks.